# Include SQLite in Click-Once Application?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlite, deployment

I'm trying to figure out how to include SQLite in a click-once program that will be distributed on the Internet.

Currently I have the SQLite database in the /bin folder and it all works.

Should I be using the /bin folder to insure the database is included with the published program?

My connection string has the complete path to the /bin folder that uses my user-name, etc. But that path will not be know at run-time.

I'm guessing I need to find the path to the database in Form1_Load( ) and change the connection string? But I don't know how to find the path.

Am I on the right track here?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you put a relative path or use the app_data folder?

Comment: Can you tell me please how to find the relative path and app_data folder?

Comment: [Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx)

Comment: This seems to work:

Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)).FullName

Answer (score 0):

use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get the execution path for your application :)